# One word or accurate phrase for upgrading previously learnt skills

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, verbs

I am building my resume to apply for jobs and placement drives as I have started my last year of computer engineering.
This is the objective/ intro part of my resume:

> I am a 4th Year Computer Engineering student looking for entry-level opportunities specifically in the Data Science, Cloud Computing, and DevOps domain to deepen my knowledge and hone my skills. I am looking for challenging roles to learn new skills and **amend my prior ones.**

I want the perfect word to fit the bold part of the sentence, which is to amend my prior ones.

I want express that I am looking for roles in which I can learn new skills and like upgrade the ones I already have.

I can also keep the word ***amend*** if required but I need an accurate word for ***my prior ones***

Comment: Don't use "amend". It sounds as if there is something wrong with your existing skills that has to be corrected.

Comment: Update.  That is the verb you want for a resume.  Update existing skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say

> ...and **develop my existing** ones.

The use of 'amend' is inappropriate here. It suggests there is something *wrong* with the skills you have.

Also the use of 'prior' suggests they are skills which you have lost.

Answer (score 1):

You're best off ditching *prior* and *amend* because they read horribly.
Instead simply use *develop my XYZ skills*.  Or *develop my XYZ skills further*.

Comment: How does this improve on my earlier answer?